# what's the difference between the installed version of tomcat 7 and the myeclipse's tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, myeclipse, webproject

too much similar versions they looks like each other. 
Sometimes i dont know to choose a suitable version for my project.

just like myeclipse tomcat and  the installed version of tomcat 7  or some version just like

core version , extra, or....

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly different configuration, otherwise they are the same. The different configuration in MyEclipse defines a shared.loader which points to the JAX-WS libraries in MyEclipse, so they may need to be added to an application for an externally installed Tomcat 7.

Comment: thanks a lot. I need to search more about jax-ws lib. Cause is I try to change the context of the project when i use the myeclipse , i dont know the location of this. thanks again.

Comment: Context is given in the properties for the Project (right click on the project and select Properties). The context will be in the MyEclipse section, either under Web or under Project Facets/Web, depending on the release of MyEclipse.